# Why i have two messages after load page in console using AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I'm creating a AngularJS Application, and in JS-Controlleri at the top i wrote the **console.log()** message:

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", ['ngRoute']);
myApp.controller("defaultController", function ($scope, $location, logicOfMyApp) {
    console.log("My daddy is duck, my mommy is duck and i'm duck too ...");
});
```

and after load the page i has two messages:
[image]

Why i have two messages ?

P.S.I cleared console before loading the page.

Routing Script:

```
myApp.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider.when('/', {
    templateUrl: "Partials/Books.html",
    controller: "defaultController"
})
.when('/books', {
    templateUrl: "Partials/Books.html",
    controller: "defaultController"
})
.when('/albums', {
    templateUrl: "Partials/Albums.html",
    controller: "defaultController"
})
.when('/audios', {
    templateUrl: "Partials/Audios.html",
    controller: "defaultController"
})
.when('/videos', {
    templateUrl: "Partials/Videos.html",
    controller: "defaultController"
})
.when('/album/:albumId', {
    templateUrl: "Partials/PhotosOfAlbum.html",
    controller: "defaultController"
})
;

$routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
}]);
```

Comment: can you show the routing script?

Comment: Remove `ng-controller="defaultController"` from template.

Comment: can you show us your `html` file and `route` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Reasons:**

First one is when you load the application it goes through all the controller code.

Second one is since you are using ngRoute when the page gets routed to the specific controller it gets printed.

In Order to avoid, you need to remove `ng-controller="defaultController"` from your view if you have mentioned in the config.

Answer (score 1):

you are using `defaultController` for `/` and `/videos` so your controller initialize two times so change the controller for either of the routes and you wont see the log two times